# Programmatically posting to Asp.net/IIS web portal as the user/Screen scrape - redirection

Tags: vb.net, iis, web-scraping, screen-scraping, multipartform-data

I am trying to modifiy a vb.net 2005 in production Clinician software suite.  Prior to a recent update by the state ran insurance site this program successfully used a screen scrape to log into the site using the users login information and would upload, download etc to the site using HTTPWebRequest.  Most of the work was done using the HTTPWebRequest and the HTTPWebResponse.  The download had needed to use SOAP, but all of this was working prior to my employment for several years.

Last week the state site changed significantly and the state agency is not really working with me so I am on my own. This is in the body of the page when I look at source.

```
<form method="post" action="/hcp/Default.aspx?alias=www.ohcaprovider.com/hcp/provider"  onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
```

The first difference I noticed is that the first page is doing a PostBack to itself we used to post the parameters on the end of the next pages Url.

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

Also the first page only wants a login name and no matter what you put in manually will proceed to the next page (as this is a post back I am assuming it has a redirect going on too).  However if I set up the HTTPWebRequest it always gives me a Status 200 and the response is the default page (which is also the first page) of the web portal.

I have really researched and hunted to find answers.  I am a new person to posting to forums, and I really welcome and need some help.

I have installed firebug and noticed that when I post manually it shows me in the post what appears to be a design for a multipart/form data.  I have attempted to copy and put on HTTPWebRequest, but It is not giving me anything but a status 200 and the response is the default page again.  Below I will try to piece the code together as it is in different OOP pieces.

Basically I set up Httpwebrequest, add headers, get page, scrape for __ViewState, set up the multipart/form, set up post httpwebrequest, post and then I don't get what I expect.  I'm not sure what to expect or if one(or more) pieces of this code is not working right. Thank you again for any help.

```
    Dim lsViewState As String = "__VIEWSTATE"" value="""
    Try
        'Section of code to get the upload form GET
        chwrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.ohcaprovider.com/hcp/Default.aspx?alias=www.ohcaprovider.com/hcp/provider")
        chwrRequest.Method = "GET"
        chwrRequest.KeepAlive = True
        chwrRequest.CookieContainer = cckcCookieContainer
        ' Configure the web request to work with a proxy, like ACT
        If pobjProxy Is Nothing Then
           pobjProxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
           pobjProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        End If
        chwrRequest.Proxy = pobjProxy

        'ADD Headers
        chwrRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"  
        chwrRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        chwrRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en")
        chwrRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "windows-1252, utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859-1;q=0.6, *;q=0.1")
        chwrRequest.KeepAlive = True

        'Get Page
        chrsResponse = chwrRequest.GetResponse()
        cstmStream = chrsResponse.GetResponseStream()
        lsResp = CSubmitterUtils.GetStreamContent(cstmStream)

        cstmStream.Close()
        chrsResponse.Close()
        CSubmitterUtils.WriteFileContent(psSaveAs, lsResp)  **writes to file for debug purposes

        'Store cookie Date
        fsCookieData = cckcCookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(New Uri(OHCA_WEB_NEW))

        'Section of code to do fill form and upload file SCRAPE for viewSTATE
        Dim lnViewStateURLIndex As Integer = csResp.IndexOf(lsViewState)

        If lnViewStateURLIndex < 0 Then
            WriteLog("ViewState not found")
            lbReturn = False
        End If

        Dim lnStartIndex As Integer = lnViewStateURLIndex + lsViewState.Length
        Dim lnEqualIndex As Integer = csResp.IndexOf("=", lnStartIndex)
        Dim lsViewStateContents As String = csResp.Substring(lnStartIndex, lnEqualIndex - lnStartIndex)

        'Setup to POST
        chwrequest = WebRequest.Create(psUrl)
        chwrRequest.Method = "POST"
        chwrRequest.KeepAlive = True
        chwrRequest.CookieContainer = cckcCookieContainer
        ' Configure the web request to work with a proxy, like ACT
        If pobjProxy Is Nothing Then
           pobjProxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
           pobjProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        End If
        chwrRequest.Proxy = pobjProxy

        'ADD Headers
        chwrRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"  
        chwrRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        chwrRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en")
        chwrRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "windows-1252, utf-8, utf-16, iso-8859-1;q=0.6, *;q=0.1")
        chwrRequest.KeepAlive = True
        chwrRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False

        'Setup multipart/form
        SetupLogonFileSubmit(lsViewStateContents)
        Dim lmpBuffer As MultiPartBuffer
        Dim lsContentType As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="
        dim csBoundary = "------------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")

        lmpBuffer.ContentTypeHeader = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & csBoundary.Substring(2)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "__EVENTTARGET")  
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "__EVENTARGUMENT")  
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType +  "__LASTFOCUS")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "__VIEWSTATE")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsViewStateContents + "=")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "dnn$ctr1842$Login$UserIdCmnTextBox$Control")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(psLogName)

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "dnn$ctr1842$Login$LoginCmnButton")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("Log In")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "ScrollTop")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("")

        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(csBoundary)
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine(lsContentType + "__dnnVariable")
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine()
        lmpBuffer.WriteLine("{""__scdoff"":""1""}")

        lmpBuffer.CloseBuffer()

        Dim lsMpContent As String = lmpBuffer.ToString()
        chwrRequest.ContentLength = lsMpContent.Length
        chwrRequest.ContentType = lmpBuffer.HttpContentTypeHeader

        Dim lbyBytesBuff As Byte()
        lbyBytesBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lsMpContent)

        cstmStream = chwrRequest.GetRequestStream()
        cstmStream.Write(lbyBytesBuff, 0, lbyBytesBuff.Length)
        cstmStream.Close()

       'Get the Response 
        chrsResponse = chwrRequest.GetResponse()
       'Put it in a stream
        cstmStream = chrsResponse.GetResponseStream()

        If chrsResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Or chrsResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Found Then
            lsResp = CSubmitterUtils.GetStreamContent(cstmStream)
            cstmStream.Close()
        Else
            lsResp = ""
        End If

        chrsResponse.Close()
        CSubmitterUtils.WriteFileContent(psSaveAs, lsResp) **Previously this was then used to move on to the next page for scraping/posting
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use firebug to help me fix the multipart form.  one of the problems was that I needed to put quotes around the names.  Also we added a cookie-container to the setup of the post.  After that in order to keep moving through the pages, we obtained parameters and built multi-part forms.  We have gotten all the way to the last page.  I am going to post that question as a new question.
Thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is most of the solution.  If you still have questions I will try to help any way I can.

If Not IsNothing(chcjCookieJar) Then
    chcjCookieJar = New CookieContainer
   End If

Put this before your first GET to the site

I delineated all the code I used for the example so It would take me hours to do the same for the solution.

We have class that is called MulitPartBuffer

Basically after we GET the fist page we set up the Multipart form to post

lmpBuffer = ConstructLogonFileBuffer(.LoginLogAction)

If Not IsNothing(lmpBuffer) Then
     lsMpContent = lmpBuffer.ToString()
     chwrRequest.ContentType = lmpBuffer.HttpContentTypeHeader

```
 lbyBytesBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lsMpContent)
 chwrRequest.ContentLength = lbyBytesBuff.Length

 cstmStream = chwrRequest.GetRequestStream()
 cstmStream.Write(lbyBytesBuff, 0, lbyBytesBuff.Length)
 cstmStream.Close()
Else
 WriteLog("Error writing to buffer.")
End If
```

Then after setting up handle we submit

```
'Get the Response 
 chrsResponse = chwrRequest.GetResponse()
 'Put it in a stream
 cstmStream = chrsResponse.GetResponseStream()
 'Write to Log, displayed on screen
  WriteLog("ResponseCode: " + chrsResponse.StatusCode.ToString())

 If chrsResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    lsResp = CSubmitterUtils.GetStreamContent(cstmStream)
    cstmStream.Close()
Else
    lsResp = ""
End If

chrsResponse.Close()
```

We save the result

```
CSubmitterUtils.WriteFileContent(psSaveAs, lsResp)
```

How we construct the multi part form (the .Variables (psContentType) are the values we got out of firebug by looking at the POST results)
if there is a , it expects a value (psFileContent) too which we either get from the cookies, screen scrape or our users info)

```
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.EventTarget)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.EventArgument)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.LastFocus)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.ViewStatePost, csViewStateContents)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.ViewStateEncrypted)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.LoginControl, TheLogin)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.LoginLogAction, psLogAction)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.ScrollTop)
lmpBuffer.AddFilePartGeneric(.dnnVariablePost)
lmpBuffer.CloseBuffer()

Public Sub AddFilePartGeneric(ByVal psContentType As String, Optional ByVal psFileContent As String = "")
  AddFilePart(Content-Disposition: form-data; name=, "", psContentType, psFileContent, Nothing)
End Sub
```

NOTE:  This sub is not labeled correctly (we reused code so the parameter names are not really very friendly)

```
Public Sub AddFilePart(ByVal psFieldName As String, ByVal psFileName As String, ByVal contentType As String, ByVal fileContent As String, ByVal contentTransferEncoding As String)
    Try
        WriteLine("------------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"))

        If Not contentType Is Nothing Then
            WriteLine(psFieldName + contentType)
        End If

        WriteLine()
        WriteLine(fileContent)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Cache.WriteException(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When stepping through you should be able to view lsMpContent and it should MATCH EXACTLY WHAT FIREBUG HAS ON ITS POST FOR MULTIPART FORM)

The cookiejar will enable you to then repeat the process for the subsequent pages, all you have to do is set up the multi-part form correctly and add any parameters to the handle.

Please NOTE: It has been many days since working on this.  I may not have firebug terminology exact.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

.NET sites are often among the more difficult to scrape.  This blog posting may help:

http://blog.screen-scraper.com/2008/06/04/scraping-aspnet-sites/

Feel free to contact us directly at screen-scraper.com if you end up hitting a wall with your project.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the link.  I have managed to scrape and maneuver all the way to the last piece, downloading from a link. If you have any helpful suggestions on setting up the GET properly for this, I would really appreciate it. also I can cannot seem to get the link you posted to display.